# Working with large csv file in R

Tags: r, bigdata, large-files

any help will be appreciated.

I used the following code to break down my large csv file (4gb) and now I am trying to save the 2nd, 3rd... part into a csv. However, I can only access the first chunk of my data.

Is there anything wrong with my code? 
How do I save the second chunk of my data into csv?

```
rgfile <- 'filename.csv' 

index <- 0  

chunkSize <- 100000

con <- file(description = rgfile, open="r")

dataChunk <- read.table(con, nrows= chunkSize, header=T, fill= TRUE, sep= ",")

actualColumnNames <- names(dataChunk)

repeat {

  index <- index + 1 

  print(paste('Processing rows:', index * chunkSize)) 

  if (nrow(dataChunk) != chunkSize){
    print('Processed all files!')
    break
  }

  dataChunk <- read.table(
    con, nrows = chunkSize, skip=0, header = FALSE, 
    fill=TRUE, sep = ",", col.names=actualColumnNames
  ) 

  break

}
```

Comment: You're overwriting `dataChunk` each time through the loop. Do you want to write each chunk? If so, there should be a `write.csv` statement after the `read.table`. Also, `skip` needs to be set to the first row you want to start reading from each time through the loop. Use the `nrows` argument to set the total number of rows to read. Consider using `read_csv` from the `readr` package or `fread` from the `data.table` package. Both are much faster than `read.table` or `read.csv`.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I really appreciate it. You are correct, I am trying to write each chunk as its own file. If you don't mind can you share how you would incorporate the write.csv code because I attempted to save it a multiple time but I keep receiving an error.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Error: unexpected input in:
"    dChunk = read.table(conn, nrows = chunk, skip=0, header = FALSE, fill =TRUE, sep = ",", col.names=actualColumnNames)  
    write.csv(dChunk, file = ‘"
>     
>     break
Error: no loop for break/next, jumping to top level
>     
> }
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"

Comment: (Please do not include extensive code or console output in comments, for two reasons: (1) it can be hard to read, especially when multiple lines; and (2) readers looking to solve their own problems do not always see all comments. Please edit your question and insert the error there.)

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

# make the problelm reproducible
rgfile <- 'flights.csv' 
write_csv(flights, rgfile)

# now, get to work

lines <- as.numeric(R.utils::countLines(rgfile))

chunk_size <- 100000

hdr <- read_csv(rgfile, n_max=2)

fnum <- 1

for (i in seq(1, lines, chunk_size)) {

  suppressMessages(
    read_csv(
      rgfile, col_names=colnames(hdr), skip=(i-1), n_max=chunk_size
    )
  ) -> x

  if (i>1) colnames(x) <- colnames(hdr)

  write_csv(x, sprintf("file%03d.csv", fnum))

  fnum <- fnum + 1

}
```