# How to set a limit to output csv file in R?

Tags: r

If my output file is of 16MB, and I set the limit as 5MB, it should produce 4 files, three of 5MB each and one of 1MB.

Alternatively, it can have a condition of max row numbers in a file. Say, file with 16k row items, having a condition of 5k row items should produce 4 files, three of 5k row items, one of 1k row items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple solution:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(readr) # for faster write_csv

df <- flights

# number of items in each chunk
elements_per_chunk <- 100000

# list of rows for each chunk
l <- split(1:nrow(df), ceiling(seq_along(1:nrow(df))/elements_per_chunk))

# splits and saves csv files
for(i in 1:length(l)){
  print(i) # totally optional, gives some feedback on progress
  write_csv(df[l[[i]],],
              file=paste0("flights_chunk", i, ".csv"), )
}
```

ideas from
https://gist.github.com/KobaKhit/abfef3f4c5ef293bc2aa739b90edeabb
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47320674

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
writeCSV_group <- function(x, nMB=NULL, nrow=NULL, stem=NULL, ...){
  if(!is.null(nMB) & !is.null(nrow))stop("Only one of nMB or nrow can be specified.\n")
  if(is.null(nMB) & is.null(nrow))stop("One of nMB or nrow must be specified.\n")
  size_metric <- ifelse(is.null(nMB), "rows", "size")
  size_val <- ifelse(is.null(nMB), nrow, nMB)
  size_fun <- switch(size_metric, 
                     "size" = function(x)object.size(x)/(1024^2), 
                     "rows" = nrow)
  obj.size <- size_fun(x)
  class(obj.size) <- "numeric"
  nrx <- nrow(x)
  sizePerRow <- obj.size/nrx
  gsize <- ceiling(size_val/sizePerRow)
  nGroups <- ceiling(obj.size/size_val)
  g <- rep(1:nGroups, each = gsize)
  g <- g[1:nrx]
  s <- split(x, g)
  stem <- ifelse(is.null(stem), gsub(".*\\/(.*)$", "\\1", tempfile()), stem)
  fn <- paste0(stem, "_", 1:nGroups, ".csv")
  for(i in 1:length(fn)){
    write.csv(s[[i]], fn[i], ...)
  }
  cat("files written as:\n  ", 
      paste(fn, collapse="\n  "), sep="")
}
```

You could either specify `nMB` as the number of megabytes per group or `nrow` as the number of rows per group.  The `stem` argument is to allow you to provide a file name as the stem.